# What is the docker command to run my Django server?

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, server, docker-compose

I'm trying to Dockerize my local Django/MySql setup.  I have this directory and file structure ...

```
apache
docker-compose.yml
web
    - manage.py
    - venv
    - requirements.txt
    - ...
```

Below is the docker-compose.yml file I'm using ...

```
version: '3'  

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    #env_file: web/venv
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: [ "python", "./web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]

  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3406"
    expose:
      # Opens port 3406 on the container
      - '3406'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:
  my-db:
```

However when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I get errors like the below

```
maps_web_1 exited with code 2
web_1    | python: can't open file './web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
maps_web_1 exited with code 2
maps_web_1 exited with code 2
web_1    | python: can't open file './web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
maps_web_1 exited with code 2
```

Is there another way I'm supposed to be referencing the manage.py file?

**Edit:** Added info requested in comments ...

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Comment: Please share Dockerfile in your 'web' dir

Comment: Hi @drd, I have added the file you requested

Comment: Most probably, command is triggered from different directory, I have modified answer, to set working directory in container and to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others suggested, this is most probably because of running the `manage.py runserver` from a wrong directory or something very similar to this.

You are not using `WORKDIR` directive in your `Dockerfile`, at all. It is much safer if you do use them. Change your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files as below, and you problem should be solved.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'  

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    #env_file: web/venv
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
...
```

**Notice**

You should be able to fix the problem by simply deleting `web` from your command for running the server. That's because when you are building the `Dockerfile`, you are inside the `web` directory. So when you do `COPY . .` you are copying contents inside `web` directory, and not the `web` directory itself. Actually, your file structure inside the docker image, should look something similar to this:

```
- root
- home
- var
- ...
- manage.py
- venv
- requirements.txt
- ...
```

Comment: I copied web/Dockerfile exactly as you have it, changed the "command" in docker-compose.yml to what you have, ran "docker-compose up" but am getting the error, " python: can't open file '/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: I think the problem might be because of the volume you are mounting. What is this volume supposed to do? Try pointing the command to `/usr/src/app/` too. I have also edited the answer a little bit.

Comment: I don't know what the "volumes" do -- I copied this configuration from somewhere else, so maybe I don't need that stuff?  Anyway I updated the Dockerfile with your change (you only edited "COPY . /app/", is that right?), but I still get the error upon startup, "python: can't open file '/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: Are you building the docker image after changing the `Dockerfile` before running it?

Comment: I first ran "docker-compose down --rmi all" and then "docker-compose up" from the directory in which docker-compose.yml lives.

Comment: Can you change the command to something like `["sh", "-c", "pwd && tail -f /dev/null"]` and see what the output is?

Comment: Sure, it prints out "web_1    | /app".  I have also checked everything into a Github if that's easier to see -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps .

Comment: Then change the `[ "python", "/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]` to this `[ "python", "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]`. I have also edited the answer. @Dave

Comment: That results in the error, "web_1    | python: can't open file 'manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".  Also updated the GitHub repo with your suggestion.

Comment: Will you try this one too? `["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

Comment: There's no error returned from "docker-compose up" when I do that, but running "curl http://127.0.0.1:8000" results in a "curl: (52) Empty reply from server".

Comment: Well thats probably a problem in your application.

Comment: Unlikely since when I switch to my "web" directory, run "source venv/bin/activate", then "python manage.py runserver 8000", I'm able to visit "http://localhost:8000/" and see my start page.  If my application had a problem, this path I'm describing would fail as well, no?

Comment: I think you should bind your localhost's 8000 port to inside the container. Change the `expose` line in `docker-compose.yml` to `ports: 8000:8000`

Comment: That's looking real good.  Let me run a few more tests but I thnk we've got a winner!

Answer (score 0):

In the `command:` directive, if you're using the array syntax, you're responsible for breaking up the command into words.  As you've shown it you're running the equivalent of `python "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` at the shell prompt, and it's dutifully considering the entire command and options as the filename of a script to be run, including spaces.  If you break this up into single words it will work better

```
command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

But there's not really a reason to specify this in `docker-compose.yml` at all.  This is the default command you'd want to run to launch the container no matter how you ran it, so it should be the default command in your image's `Dockerfile`

```
...
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

You don't need `links:` at all on modern Docker (Docker Compose [automatically sets up inter-container networking for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)).  You definitely don't want to mount named volumes over your application code: this hides what's in your image, and (since you've told Docker this is critical user data) it forces Docker to use an old version of your application if you try to update your image.

That leaves you with a simpler `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'      
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:           # to access the container from outside
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'

  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3306"  # second port is always container-internal port
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

Comment: I ran "docker-compose down --rmi all" then "docker-compose up" but keep seeing these many colorful messages, "maps_web_1 exited with code 0".  Ideally, how should I know that everything launched successfully?

Comment: "Exited with code 0" means that the process finished successfully (but you don't actually expect that for a server-type process).  Do you in fact have the correct `CMD` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: If I were able to telnet to 0.0.0.0 on port 8000 would that be one indication I have the right command?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address meaning "everywhere", and telnet is a very old interactive terminal protocol, so not really.  You should be able to `curl http://localhost:8000` from the host (if you're not using Docker Toolbox) and that should connect to the service.

Comment: @David Maze You should check service accessibility, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and yes, it's better to put this content into `entrypoint.sh` and call in through the command directive.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to debug this error:

```
maps_web_1 exited with code 2
web_1    | python: can't open file './web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Looks like either code is not not copied to container (named 'web') or command is triggered from root/home directory, where *manage.py* is not accessible.

**1. Is the code available on container? How to check?**

Usually, docker will just commands in container execute and exit unless there is unfinished running task (like server running in background). 
To stop exiting and enable debugging it, let us add a *running* command, so that you can login to *container* and see if code is present.

*command: tail -f /dev/null* #trick to keep the docker alive for debug mode.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    #env_file: web/venv
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: tail -f /dev/null #trick to keep the docker alive for debug mode.
```

2. Login to container 'web', from command line run `docker exec -it web bash`

Check if project files are present, now you can run `python manage.py runserver 8000` command manually. If it works, then we can be sure of that the server can be run on container. Now, we can analyse initial working directory.

3. If code is present, check why manage.py is not found? **Is the working directory set?** meaning, does the container know what is the base directory to run command?

   Specify which is the working directory, in *Dockerfile*, before you copy the project files in to container.

*Dockerfile* in web directory

```
        ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
        ARG PROJ_DIR=/usr/project/web
        RUN mkdir -p $PROJ_DIR
        WORKDIR $PROJ_DIR
        COPY . $WORKDIR
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
        restart: always
        build: ./web
        expose:
          - "8000"
        links:
          - mysql:mysql
        volumes:
          - web-django:/usr/src/app
          - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
        #env_file: web/venv
        environment:
          DEBUG: 'true'
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 #note this command is triggered from $WORKDIR that we set in Dockerfile.
```

I think this should resolve the issue or help you to figure out the problem.

Comment: I was confused about what directives went in what files from your post, but I tried putting the "working_dir" and "command" in the docker-compose.yml file, but got this error upon running "docker-compose up" ... "ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: the working directory './web' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project."

Comment: `docker-compose run web bash` will give you an interactive shell in the runtime environment matching the container, without needing to edit the `docker-compose.yml` file.  You can specify an alternate `command:` at the command line.

Comment: In this case, @Dave's container is exiting as soon as he runs it, so he won't be able to log in to container terminal.